# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a website up and I have a dropdown navigation and it doesn't seem to work on the index page. It works fine with every other link/page. The code is the same for each page but it doesn't work on the index page.

[Working drop down:] (http://beta.dtc.bz)

[Not Working drop down:] (http://beta.dtc.bz/play)

Here is the code:
    `<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li> -->
    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon!</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>`

Can someone figure out what is happening with the drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://beta.dtc.bz/play` works for me

`http://beta.dtc.bz/` dosen't work for me

On `http://beta.dtc.bz/` you include the bootstrap.min.js 2 times witch if you remove one then it works.

You also include jquery 2 times on the index page.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>`

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>`